# Completion blocks

Tags: ios, xcode, nsxml, completion-block

In my viewController i create an instance of the class QuestionParser which will start a xml parser. My question is: IS there the possibility so the parser will not finish parsing before the program reaches compblock, thus returning nil argument or even an error ?

MenuViewController.m

```
QuestionParser *parser = [[QuestionParser alloc]init];
[parser parseCategories:^(NSArray *categoryName, NSArray *categoryID)
{
    if(categoryName)
    {
        NSlog(@"%@",categoryName);
    }
}];
```

QuestionParser.m

> (void) parseCategories:(myCategoryCompletion) compblock
>   {
>
> [self parseCategories];
>
> ```
> compblock(categoryName,categoryID);
> ```
>
> }

I am sorry i didn't provide all the info, and i will try to clarify the situation. in `parseCategories` function i do this:

> -(void) parseCategories {
>
> ```
>   NSLog(@"<> start parsing categories <>");
>
>   categoryParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[URL]];
>
>   [categoryParser setDelegate:self];
>
>   [categoryParser parse]; 
> }
> ```

And i expect so the completion block does not end before my parser's delegate "`didFinishDocument`" reaches. Will this be the case ?

Now, while testing this functions, everything works ok, my parser delegates create the arrays i need from the xml and after that, it reaches the end on the block compblock(categoryName,categoryID) returning to the view controller what i need. I wander if the parser takes to long will it still work ?

Comment: Can't understand the question.

Comment: You haven't given enough information about the `parseCategories` method.

Comment: We'd need to see the implementation of `parseCategories:` in order to answer your question.

Comment: If QuestionParser build at event based parser like NSXMLParser - possible (you not pass block to method called at end of parsing document). Otherwise - not enough info about QuestionParser implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to worry about that. The "parse" of NSXMLParser is synchronous. Unless the completion or failure returns, "parse" will be over.